# Is it possible to create a drive partition using a batch file

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to code a program that needs it's own drive partition with it's own Drive Letter (Eg, G: ,C:) First, is it possible, second if it is, how do I do it?
Is there a program I need to install

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, on a Windows PC, using a [PowerShell script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/new-partition?view=win10-ps). Save the following as a.ps1 script.

> New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter

You can set `Size`, rather than use `UseMaximumSize`, with the size measured in Bytes (default), or specified in Bytes, KB, MB, GB, or TB.

`AssignDriveLetter` picks the next available drive letter, which might be different on different machines, of course. or specify `DriveLetter`, taking the chance that letter is not in use (everyone picks `X` or `Z`, since *no one* would ever use that ;-)

For help, see [this](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-xp-vista/create-run-powershell-script/) on scripting.

Not bad for one line of code!

Comment: You can also use DISKPART - the DISKPART program has a /s option which causes it to run commands from a file.